# canvas toDataURL is not converting base64 string to real image

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to create a function which compress the image after selecting and append it to the body.

**Here is my code =>**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Image Compression</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" id="random-img" />
  </body>
  <script>
    const Compress = function (img_obj, quality, output_format) {
      var mime_type = output_format;
      var cvs = document.createElement("canvas");

      img_obj.onload = function () {
        cvs.width = img_obj.naturalWidth;
        cvs.height = img_obj.naturalHeight;
      };

      var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d").drawImage(img_obj, 0, 0);
      var newImageData = cvs.toDataURL(mime_type, quality / 100);

      var result_image_obj = new Image();
      result_image_obj.src = newImageData;
      return result_image_obj;
    };

    function getImg() {
      const src_obj = document.getElementById("random-img").files[0];
      const newImg = new Image();
      newImg.src = URL.createObjectURL(src_obj);
      const compressed_img = Compress(newImg, 80, src_obj.type);
      document.querySelector("body").appendChild(compressed_img);
    }

    document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("change", getImg);
  </script>
</html>
```

The problem is I am not able to see the image on the screen.Instead I see any empty white box of 300 x 150 size when I open the developer tool and hover over the image element.

Please help! Thankyou!

Comment: Not that this will solve all your problems, but do note that `img_obj.onload` is "async" and thus your code that follows it outside that scope will execute immediately before the image has loaded.

Comment: @GetSet Thanks, I did not knew that onload is async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

img_obj.onload() is asynchronous, you can't just immediately return from it.

```js
 const Compress = function (img_obj, quality, output_format) {
    var mime_type = output_format;
    var cvs = document.createElement("canvas");

    img_obj.onload = function () {
      cvs.width = img_obj.naturalWidth;
      cvs.height = img_obj.naturalHeight;

      var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d").drawImage(img_obj, 0, 0);
      var newImageData = cvs.toDataURL(mime_type, quality / 100);

      var result_image_obj = new Image();
      result_image_obj.src = newImageData;
      document.querySelector("body").appendChild(result_image_obj);
    };
  };

  function getImg() {
    const src_obj = document.getElementById("random-img").files[0];
    const newImg = new Image();
    newImg.src = URL.createObjectURL(src_obj);
    const compressed_img = Compress(newImg, 80, src_obj.type);
  }

  document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("change", getImg);
```

```html
 <input type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" id="random-img" />
```